# Flatten rows in psql created as a "nested" structure

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that has columns *name* and *id*, but the *id* can be also a *name*, so, the structure is nested like this:

```
    name     id
    NAME01 | ID01
    NAME02 | ID02
    NAME03 | ID03
    NAME03 | ID03_1
    ID03_1 | ID051
    ID03_1 | ID061
    NAME04 | ID04
    ID04   | ID04_1
    ID04_1 | ID05
```

Is there a way in psql to "flatten" these groups by removing all intermediate values, for eg:

From these rows:

```
    NAME03 | ID03
    NAME03 | ID03_1
    ID03_1 | ID051
    ID03_1 | ID061
```

I want to retrieve these rows:

```
    NAME03 | ID03  // this remain the same
    NAME03 | ID051 // this actually was NAME03, ID03_1 and ID03_1, ID051
    NAME03 | ID061 // this actually was NAME03, ID03_1 and ID03_1, ID061
```

the intermediary row ID03_1 is ignored.

Comment: Is "NAMExx" always the top-most parent?

Comment: it's not a rule to name the top-most as NAMExxx, it can be other name

Comment: Well, it makes the routine much more complicated if one needs to find the top-most or bottom-most elements beforehand. Is there any indicator which allows to identify the roots or leafs?

Comment: no indicators of root nodes or leaf nodes